# Caliburn Micro - automatic creation of ViewModel objects from a ItemSource binding of Model classes?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, mvvm, caliburn.micro

Is it possible in Caliburn Micro to inject a ViewModel object between the view and the model when binding to a collection of model objects?

For example, if I had a `IShellViewModel` with the following property:

```
IEnumerable<Foo> Foos { get; set; }
```

and a ListBox in the ShellView.xaml

```
<ListBox x:Name="Foos"/>
```

Which would use FooView to render the listbox items.  Can Caliburn inject a collection of IEnumerable for the View to bind to?  Or do I have to create a parallel collection of IEnumerable next to the original model's IEnumerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking, when you say 'which would use FooView to render the listbox items', do you mean you have 1 view which renders ALL of the items, or a view per item?

If it's the latter, then Caliburn.Micro has a convention where if you have a collection of view models (e.g `IEnumerable<FooViewModel>`) bound to an `ItemsControl`, then it will search for a `FooView` for each of the items and automatically bind the located view to that item's view model.

If you're asking if Caliburn.Micro can autogenerate ViewModel types from your model types, then no. How would it know what properties to expose? Normally a view model reshapes and enhances the functionality of a model, including presentation logic which would be specific to a particular UI technology.

Comment: Yes, the latter. A collection of FooViewModel works fine.  My question is what does Caliburn do for you if you have a dynamic collection of IEnumerable<Foo> instead.  Will Caliburn create the appropriate FooViewModel object to bridge to the model objects?

Comment: As mentioned in the last part of the answer, this wouldn't really be possible, and would be undesirable anyway. Why are you after this functionality?

Comment: To avoid needing to create a tracking collection of ViewModels. Otherwise, for every dynamic collection in the model I would need to create a parallel collection of View-model objects (tracking the original model collection using INCC).  Not a huge deal, but it would be nicer if Caliburn created the ViewModel objects to wrap the model objects on demand.

Comment: That would be useful, we did think of something similar ourselves using generics and the model and view model types as generic parameters, but it wasn't anything more than initial talks. As I say, I don't think you'd want to auto generate view model types, but you could certainly write the boilerplate code for managing the collections in a generic fashion.

Comment: Right, I've written a generic ViewModel tracking collection using generic parameters.  This works OK.  But I would prefer Caliburn to use a model where the ViewModel are recycled and attached to the Model objects when needed.  This is quite similar how Silverlight/WPF work with element virtualization in databinding.